# Como puedo obtener informacion de una carpeta en cbuilder Embarcadero

Tags: c++, c++builder

Tengo la direccion de una carpeta.  Que código puedo utilizar para conocera los nombres de las carpetas y archivos que están dentro de esa carpeta de la cual tengo la direccion. Yo quiero conocer los nombres de los archivos y carpetas que hay en la direccion que yo tengo, que es la de una carpeta. En c++ cbuilder(Embarcadero)

Comment: El IDE que estés usando no influencia en la manera de tomar los datos del sistema de archivos, será el sistema operativo el que se encargue de ello. ¿Podrías mostrarnos qué has intentado hasta ahora?.

Comment: Nesecitamos ver que es lo que haz intentado hasta ahora para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 1):

Como comentan los compañeros más arriba, sin especificar más detalles solo puedo decirte que hay varias maneras, ya sea usando la API de Windows, o las bibliotecas propias de C++Builder.

Un ejemplo muy simple por si te sirve para empezar a buscar más detalles. Muestra todos los archivos y directorios de la ruta especificada:

```
String path = "c:\\";
String str = "Contenido de " + path + "\n";
TSearchRec sr;
bool finalizado = FindFirst(path + "\\*.*", faAnyFile, sr);
while (!finalizado)
{
    if (sr.Attr & faDirectory)
        str += "[" + sr.Name + "]\n";
    else
        str += sr.Name + "\n";

    finalizado = FindNext(sr);
}
FindClose(sr);
ShowMessage(str);
```

También puedes echarle un vistazo a los componentes **TFileListBox** y **TDirectoryListBox** de la pestaña "Win 3.1", son algo viejos, pero siguen teniendo su utilidad.

---

(Aunque la pregunta es algo vieja creo que puede ser útil para otras personas que están empezando y que busquen la pregunta en el futuro)

(Sería interesante que alguien creara la etiqueta [c++builder] al igual que la hay de otros compiladores de C++ y como existe en la versión en inglés de StackOverflow)

Comment: Gracias por crear la etiqueta y además tan rápidamente.

Comment: lista la etiqueta, fue una casualidad que viese tu respuesta tan rápido, no me había topado con la pregunta. Un saludo y +1

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas una versión *moderna* de C++ Builder, te puedes valer de la clase `TDirectory` para obtener un listado de todos los archivos contenidos en una carpeta. Específicamente del método [`GetFiles`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.IOUtils.TDirectory.GetFiles).

Este método te devuelve un arreglo dinámico que contiene los nombres de los archivos.

```
TStringDynArray lista;
TSearchOption opciones;
String path = "c:\\";

opciones = TSearchOption::soTopDirectoryOnly;

lista = TDirectory::GetFiles(path, "*.*", opciones);

for (int i = 0; i < lista.Length; i++)
    hacerAlgoConElArchivo(lista[i]);
```

Una de las ventajas de hacer uso de estas clases es que, no solo el código resultante es más simple, sino que es multi-plataforma<sup>1</sup>, pues las clases encapsulan las diferencias que hay entre un sistema operativo y otro.

<sup>1</sup>: Entre las plataformas soportadas por c++ builder.